# How does one determine whether a C file is gcc compilable?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

One of the requirements for my college project is that my C file must be gcc compilable.

I do not know what this means and I do not know how to go about determining whether a C file is gcc compilable or not. How does one do this?

At the moment, I am using VS 2012 to compile my files. Part of the requirements for the submission of the code is that it must be able to be executed on the command line.

Comment: Well, compiling it with GCC comes to mind.

Answer (score 5):

Download GCC and attempt to compile the file with it.

Comment: Might also want to check it on a non-Windows system, due to case-insensitivity issues with Windows filesystems.

Comment: I believe this is in fact the most correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use headers or library functions that are specific to Windows or MSVC.  For example (and yes, I'm dating myself here) the "conio.h" file and functions declared in it are not recognized by gcc.

If you limit yourself to what's defined in the [language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), then your code will compile under gcc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started compiling with GCC on Windows is to install the version of Code::Blocks that bundles MinGW's gcc environment.

http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/5#windows

You're looking to download the `codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe`

When you create a C or C++ project with that version of Code::Blocks, gcc will be the default compiler and you're all set. (until you start needing to do anything like I/O multiplexing, at which point you'll need a real Unix install)